# Can someone explain why Anchor's ".signers([ ])" not does work with "sendTransaction" from useWallet()?

Tags: anchor, signature, signing, send-transaction

Including the `newAccount` Keypair as signer in the `initialize` instruction using the anchor format below results in a `WalletSendTransactionError: Signature verification failed` after approving from connected wallet.

```
const newAccount = Keypair.generate()

const transaction = await program.methods
  .initialize()
  .accounts({
    counter: newAccount.publicKey,
    user: wallet.publicKey,
    systemAccount: SystemProgram.programId,
  })
  .signers([newAccount]) <---- including signature here not working
  .transaction()

sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
```

It works fine if I include `newAccount` as signer in `SendTransaction`:

```
const transaction = await program.methods
  .initialize()
  .accounts({
    counter: newAccount.publicKey,
    user: wallet.publicKey,
    systemAccount: SystemProgram.programId,
  })
  .transaction()

sendTransaction(transaction, connection, { signers: [newAccount] }) <--- works like this
```

Could someone explain why the first approach does not work? I thought `.signers[( )]` included the signature in the transaction.

Using `.rpc` also works with no errors:

```
   const transaction = await program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        counter: newAccount.publicKey,
        user: wallet.publicKey,
        systemAccount: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([newAccount])    <---- works with .rpc()
      .rpc()
```

Below is the `initialize` instruction:

```
#[program]
pub mod counter {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let counter = &mut ctx.accounts.counter;
        counter.count = 0;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub counter: Account<'info, Counter>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Counter {
    pub count: u64,
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe share the Accounts struct as well for the `initialize` instruction?

Comment: Also could you try logging `transaction.signatures.map(s => s.publicKey.toBase58())` in the first case? Also just to sanity check, does the first example work if you do `.rpc()` at the end instead of `.transaction()`?

Comment: Added the ```initialize``` instruction. 

Using ```.signers([ ])``` works correctly with ```.rpc```.  
Although didn't get any signatures when I tried to console.log ```transaction.signatures.map(s => s.publicKey.toBase58())``` using ```.transaction``` with ```.signers([newAccount])```. Logged ```[]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sendTransaction](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/7d05857/src/connection.ts#L4480) method attempts to do -- too much. It should be used for simple/basic examples.

`sendTransaction` will sign and send the transaction, irrespective if it's being signed.

On line `4495`:

```
async sendTransaction(
    transaction: Transaction,
    signers: Array<Signer>,
    options?: SendOptions,
  ): Promise<TransactionSignature> {
    
    // some code was removed for brevity

        transaction.lastValidBlockHeight = latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight;
        transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
        transaction.sign(...signers);
```

It calls `.sign` with the signers that were passed in, hence why you get the `Signature verification failed` error.

[connection.sendRawTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#sendRawTransaction) or [connection.sendEncodedTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#sendEncodedTransaction) should be used instead.